# WordPress sometimes looses my custom add_rewrite_rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm developing a plugin that is adding a new rewrite rule to the .htaccess with the add_rewrite_rule function.

On plugin activation I add the new rewrite rule, then flush rules to make it work.

Everything is going fine, the rewrite rule works pretty good, except that sometimes the .htaccess loose that settings so i have to deactivate and activate again my plugin.

What could cause this behavior? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

**Update 1**

Maybe the filter flush_rewrite_rules_hard can do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the following resolved my issue:

> Add your rules on the init action and just flush on activation, when
>   some other code flushes them they will still be present.

Taken from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100897).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm sure that adding it to the init will solve the problem, but is really this the (only) correct way? I mean adding the rule on every page load? Maybe there is an hook called every refresh rules, that's probably what breaks the preexisting rule.